# python for loop 2 program with different output

Tags: python, for-loop

i was practicing with for loop and i am noob here :p

case 1-

```
Fruits = ['mango','banana','orange','grapes','apple']
for fruit in Fruits:
    print("Current fruit:",fruit)
print("Good Bye")
```

output for this code is

```
Current fruit: mango
Current fruit: banana
Current fruit: orange
Current fruit: grapes
Current fruit: apple
Good Bye
```

case 2-

```
students = ['Avinash','Arush','Akshay','Raghav','Aditya']
for student in students:
    print("Current student are:",students)
print("meet you next time")
```

output

```
Current student are: ['Avinash', 'Arush', 'Akshay', 'Raghav', 'Aditya']
Current student are: ['Avinash', 'Arush', 'Akshay', 'Raghav', 'Aditya']
Current student are: ['Avinash', 'Arush', 'Akshay', 'Raghav', 'Aditya']
Current student are: ['Avinash', 'Arush', 'Akshay', 'Raghav', 'Aditya']
Current student are: ['Avinash', 'Arush', 'Akshay', 'Raghav', 'Aditya']
meet you next time
```

Comment: you are printing list `students` not value `student`

Comment: Adding to what Andrej said - try to use more distinct variables - for example `single_student` instead of `student` - something like this helped me a lot.

Comment: It should also read 'Current student is: ... '

Comment: `student` and `students` is fine, no need to be overly explicit, just precise. Also, capital case names should be reserved for classes and such, so `Fruits` should be `fruits`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print("Current student are:",students)`

Here you are printing the entire `list` of students and not the current variable `student`. It should be

`print("Current student are:",student)`

It really helps having distinct variables.